# Is it clear and natural to say "xxx is obstructing my understanding"?

Tags: word-usage

[According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obstruct), "obstruct" means

> to block a road, passage, entrance, etc. so that nothing can go along it, or to prevent something from happening correctly by putting difficulties in its way

In the post [meaning of "in the privacy of"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/256480/118966), I said

> I guess the use of metaphor is the block that stands in my way to understand the meaning of the whole sentence ...

Could I have said it this way?

> I guess the use of metaphor **is obstructing my understanding** of the sentence.

I tried all 4 verb tenses with [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=15&content=obstructing%20my%20understanding%2C%20obstruct%20my%20understanding%2C%20obstructs%20my%20understanding%2C%20obstructed%20my%20understanding&case_insensitive=on&smoothing=3&year_end=2011&year_start=1900&direct_url=) but none returns any results.

[image]

Is it clear and natural to say "xxx is obstructing my understanding"?

Comment: It is certainly clear and grammatical. However, **stands in my way to understand** is simply wrong.

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you. How do I say it correctly?